# parallel execution in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

require join thread like feature in spring integration. If 3 threads are complete, then execute 4th thread. As shown in the picture, 3 outbound gateways running in parallel and the 4th outbound will run only after execution of first 3.

However, I am not doing splitter/aggregater so not required. Nor required any chain operation I guess because it will execute things in sequence.

parallel execution and then wait for the execution to complete 
[image]

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="publishsubscribechannel"
    task-executor="executor" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10" />
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter
id="httpOrderCreateInboundAdapter"
    channel="orderCreateInboundChannel" path="/input"
    supported-methods="GET, POST"
</int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="micros1" request-
channel="publishsubscribechannel"
reply-channel="channel1"
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="micros2" request-
channel="publishsubscribechannel"
reply-channel="channel2"
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="micros3" request-
channel="publishsubscribechannel"
</int-http:outbound-gateway>


<int-http:outbound-gateway id="micros4" request-channel="channel2"
reply-channel="channel4"

 </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use [Scatter-Gather](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) component for that publish-subscribe channel. Yes, all your gateways must return to their reply channel header to let gatherer to collect replies from them . And really after that you will be able to proceed to the `Outbound4`.